# Is it possible to pass AnyClass to generic function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Im trying to pass AnyClass to generic function like this:

```
if let arrayObjectClass = NSClassFromString("arrayObjectTypeName") {
    foo(type: arrayObjectClass)
}
```

where `foo` looks like this:

```
func foo<T>(type: T.Type) {
    ...
}
```

but it fails to compile with error:
`Cannot convert value of type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') to expected argument type 'T.Type'`

Comment: If you could, what would you do with it?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica For example, creating some generic objects and working with them. And dont check like `if type is MyClass1 else if type is MyClass2 ...`

Comment: But the `T` won't be known until runtime (because `arrayObjectClass` is an arbitrary runtime value), so it'll be of no use to the state typing offered by generics. The type system won't know anything about `arrayObjectClass` beyond it being the class of an `Any`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs a type for your `T` there. Your `AnyClass` instance is not a type. So your `foo` will need to know what the class is supposed to be. This must be done at runtime.

```swift
if let arrayObjectClass = NSClassFromString("arrayObjectTypeName") {
  try foo(class: arrayObjectClass, arrayObjectTypeName.self)
}

func foo<T>(class: AnyClass, _: T.Type) throws {
  if let error = CastError(`class`, desired: T.self)
  { throw error }
}
```

```swift
/// An error that represents casting gone wrong. ‍♀️
public enum CastError: Error {
  /// An undesired cast is possible.
  case possible

  /// An desired cast is not possible.
  case impossible
}

public extension CastError {
  /// `nil` if  an `Instance` can be cast to `Desired`. Otherwise, `.impossible`.
  init?<Instance, Desired>(_: Instance, desired _: Desired.Type) {
    self.init(Instance.self, desired: Desired.self)
  }

  /// `nil` if  a `Source` can be cast to `Desired`. Otherwise, `.impossible`.
  init?<Source, Desired>(_: Source.Type, desired _: Desired.Type) {
    if Source.self is Desired.Type
    { return nil }

    self = .impossible
  }

  /// `nil` if  an `Instance` cannot be cast to `Undesired`. Otherwise, `.possible`.
  init?<Instance, Undesired>(_: Instance, undesired _: Undesired.Type) {
    self.init(Instance.self, undesired: Undesired.self)
  }

  /// `nil` if  a `Source` cannot be cast to `Undesired`. Otherwise, `.possible`.
  init?<Source, Undesired>(_: Source.Type, undesired _: Undesired.Type) {
    guard Source.self is Undesired.Type
    else { return nil }

    self = .possible
  }
}
```